# Parse CSV text file

Tags: vbscript

I have the following CSV file that I need to parse using VBScript. The purpose of the script is too match dates.

```
"LIRRR 1M",.412900,02/08/2016
"LIRRR 3M",.222700,02/08/2016
"LIRRR 6M",.333200,02/08/2016
"LIRRR12M",1.1333300,02/08/2016
"FEDFRRRR",.333000,02/08/2016
"CCC 1YR",.550330,02/08/2016
"2YRCMT",.743300,02/08/2016
"5YRCMT",1.2503300,02/08/2016
"10YRCMT",1.860000,02/08/2016
```

Here is the code that I have written:

```
On Error Resume Next
Const ForReading = 1

Dim strSearchFor
Dim MyDate, MyWeekDay

MyDate = Date ' Assign a date.
MyWeekDay = Weekday(MyDate)

If MyWeekDay = 2 Then
    strSearchFor = Right("0" & DatePart("m", Date), 2) & "/" & _
                   Right("0" & DatePart("d", Date-3), 2) & "/" & _
                   DatePart("yyyy", Date)
Else 
    strSearchFor = Right("0" & DatePart("m", Date), 2) & "/" & _
                   Right("0" & DatePart("d", Date-1), 2) & "/" & _
                   DatePart("yyyy", Date)
End If

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\rand.mahmwd\Desktop\index.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) = 0 Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\rand.mahmwd\Desktop\error.txt")
        objFile.Write "date is not match" & vbCrLf
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
objTextFile.Close
```

if the date match or not it always create error.txt

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: if the date match or not it always create error.txt .

Comment: great >:( you completely changed your question after i gave an answer. waste of time. I deleted my answer and not bothering again. And the down-vote is not mine btw.

Comment: any suggestion to solve my problem

Comment: sorry  Ricardo C it 1st time

Comment: Is there are any header or a blank line or anything happening at the top of your text file? Everything looks fine at first blush.

Comment: thanks for answer ...no header I copied all my text file here

Comment: Research how to define and use the MS JET DB objects; they are 32-bit only, but allow you to use the CSV as a data source to build a recordset that you can loop through like any other database table. I have some usable code, but I have not used it in years, so it is "somewhere"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me under the following conditions:

- The input file must be ANSI encoded.
- All dates in the file must be of the previous work day.
- The file must not contain any other lines, including blank lines.
- The script is run on work days only.
- The previous work day isn't in the previous month.

The last precondition is due to a bug in your script. You calculate the month and year from the current date (`DatePart("m", Date)`, `DatePart("yyyy", Date)`), but the day from the date of the previous work day (`DatePart("d", Date-3)`, `DatePart("d", Date-1)`). This can be fixed by using the same date for all calculations:

```
If WeekDay(Date) = 2 Then
    MyDate = Date - 3
Else
    MyDate = Date - 1
End If

strSearchFor = Right("0" & DatePart("m", MyDate), 2) & "/" & _
               Right("0" & DatePart("d", MyDate), 2) & "/" & _
               DatePart("yyyy", MyDate)
```